# Passing Multiple Value to a single Crystal Report Parameter separated with comma

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I want to add multiple value to a single crystal report parameter separated with commas. I am able to pass all values of parameter including multiple one from my vb.code to crystal report. Now when I try to download the report it combines the comma separated values in to one. For example, if I pass id 1,2,3 to parameter @id it downloads the report of ID 123 instead of reports of ID 1, 2 and 3

```
Dim IDS As Integer 
IDS = Request.QueryString("ids")

crReportDocument.SetParameterValue("@ids", ids)
```

If I write IDs in manually like

```
 crReportDocument.SetParameterValue("@ids", "1,2,3,4")
```

it works fine but when the parameter `@ids,ids` is given it gives me the report of id no 1234 not 1,2,3,4. 
When i try these parameters in crystal reports application directly it works fine there. It also works fine in sql procedures when i execute that procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for those who at least viewed my question. changed the datatype of ids from integer to string

```
Dim IDS As Integer 

Dim IDS As String
```

Solved the Problem. The integer was omitting the comma